# function to replace null values with mean

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have an unemployment data for the 30 countries and there are some missing values but in the excel sheet these all numbers are all strings so I first convert them to floats and then if row is empty then I want to replace row with its columns mean value. Function works well doesnt return any error but when I print the data still I have the Null values

```
 data=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\OĞUZ\Desktop\employment.xlsx')
    data=data.set_index('Unnamed: 0')
    for column in data:
        for row in column:
            if len(row)>5:
                row=float(row)
                if row.isnull():
                    row=column.mean()
print(data['Argentina'].head())
```

This is what I get after print.

```
Unnamed: 0
1990   NaN
1991   NaN
1992   NaN
1993   NaN
1994   NaN
Name: Argentina, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Try this: `data = data.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(mean()))`

Comment: If you add a `print()` after `for column in data:` and you get a string, then `for row in column:` `row`is only a letter like `A`. Therefor `len(row)>5` is always False and you code does nothing.

Comment: Actually yes when I print column all I get is country names such as Argentina Turkey etc. I thought it would print the all rows in the column. What is the reason for that and how can I fix this problem within this loop?

Answer (score 0):

To fill NaNs use [`df.fillna(value)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html). For the mean use [`df.mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html). If your column is named `Argentina` this could look like below:

```
df.Argentina.fillna(df.Argentina.mean(), inplace=True)
```

The `inplace=True` is for the reassignment. The line is equivalent to

```
df.Argentina = df.Argentina.fillna(df.Argentina.mean())
```

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Argentina':[1,np.nan,2,4]}, index=[1990, 1991, 1992, 1993])
>>> df  
        Argentina
1990    1.0
1991    NaN
1992    2.0
1993    4.0

df.Argentina.fillna(df.Argentina.mean(), inplace=True)

>>> df
        Argentina
1990    1.000000
1991    2.333333
1992    2.000000
1993    4.000000
```

If you have many columns, and you want to fill the NaNs with values depending by the column, you can loop over the column names like below:

```
for name in df.columns:
    df[name].fillna(df[name].mean(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: What makes my code wrong here?

Comment: How can I fill all the empty rows with its columns mean or median values with for all rows in the dataframe? I mean how can I do what you did for only one column to all dataframe?

Comment: If you want to fill all NaN values in all columns, you can use `df.fillna(value, inplace=Ture)`. You can calcuate or set the `value`  before.

Answer (score 0):

You can either iterate over the columns, or use `DataFrame.transform` or `DataFrame.apply`.

Whichever approach you use, you'll want to:

1. Convert column values from strings to floats
2. Calculate the mean of the column
3. Use `Series.fillna` to fill the NaN values with the previously calcualted value

#### Create Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": rng.integers(5, size=10),
    "b": rng.integers(5, 10, size=10),
    "c": rng.integers(10, 15, size=10)
}).astype(str)
df.loc[2:5, :] = np.nan

# note all the numbers you see are actually strings
print(df)
     a    b    c
0    4    8   11
1    3    9   14
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN
6    0    8   12
7    0    7   10
8    0    7   13
9    4    9   13
```

#### Solution - DataFrame transform

```py
def clean_column(series):
    series = pd.to_numeric(series, downcast="float")
    avg = series.mean()
    return series.fillna(avg)

new_df = df.transform(clean_column)

print(new_df)
0  4.000000  8.0  11.000000
1  3.000000  9.0  14.000000
2  1.833333  8.0  12.166667
3  1.833333  8.0  12.166667
4  1.833333  8.0  12.166667
5  1.833333  8.0  12.166667
6  0.000000  8.0  12.000000
7  0.000000  7.0  10.000000
8  0.000000  7.0  13.000000
9  4.000000  9.0  13.000000
```